# FindNext is not updating Range.Address when using "Do Loop while" loop

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do is look for "DESC" in a range of cells, from A1 to the last used column in the 'Summary' Worksheet of my workbook. Once the code finds the searched value it will check to see if it is DESC or TERMDESC.

```
'Gets Column Letter from Column Index
Dim vArr
Dim ColLetter As String
vArr = Split(Cells(1, Lastcolumn).Address(True, False), "$")
ColLetter = vArr(0) ' -->Column NA

'Loop begins
Dim cell As Range
Dim firstCellAddress as string
Dim DescMaxNumber As Integer
Dim TermDescMaxNumber As Integer
Dim ModString as string
Dim ModNumber as integer
DescMaxNumber = 0
TermDescMaxNumber = 0

Set cell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:" & ColLetter & "1").Find("DESC", LookIn:=xlValues)

If cell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not Found"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The code will then check and see if  if it has an integer on it last two letters (for example DESCA01, string 01 is a integer) and, if it is stores it on DescMaxNumber or TermDescMaxNumber.

```
 firstCellAddress = cell.Address

'Find all cells containing DESC including TERMDESC and max numeric value
Do
    SearchString = cell.Value

    'Determines if SearchString is DESC or TermDESC *BEGINNING*
    If InStr(1, SearchString, "DESC") = 1 Then
        ModString = Right(SearchString, 2)

        If IsNumeric(ModString) = True Then
            ModNumber = CInt(ModString)

            If DescMaxNumber < ModNumber Then
                DescMaxNumber = ModNumber
            End If
        End If

    ElseIf InStr(1, SearchString, "TERMDESC") = 1 Then
        ModString = Right(SearchString, 2)

        If IsNumeric(ModString) = True Then
            ModNumber = CInt(ModString)

            If TermDescMaxNumber < ModNumber Then
                TermDescMaxNumber = ModNumber
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set cell = Range("A1:" & ColLetter & "1").FindNext(cell)
Loop While firstCellAddress <> cell.Address

MsgBox "DESC Max Number = " & DescMaxNumber
MsgBox "TERMDESC Max Number = " & TermDescMaxNumber
```

After that it should move to the next Cell with the Value of DESC. 
Here is where my problem lies: the first time I run the code it cycles through all the cells containing DESC (D1, E1, F1, and so on) and it tells me that DescMaxNumber is equal to 34 and TermDescMaxNumber is equal to 36.

If I run the code again DexcMaxNumber = 0 and TermDescMaxNumber = 0,  stepping into the code I noticed that cell.address doesn't change from D1 to E1, it just stays on D1

Thanks

Comment: peculiar, but unable to reproduce this problem :(

Comment: How are you getting Lastcolumn? Tested, only Lastcolumn not being updated correctly the second time is what could prevent this from not moving past D1.

Comment: @RicardoA I forgot to add two lines of code, it should be:
Dim Lastcolumn as integer
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Answer (score 1):

In the initial call to `Find`, it is specified that the range we are searching is on the worksheet called `Summary` in the workbook where this code is stored:

```
Set cell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:" & ColLetter & "1").Find("DESC", LookIn:=xlValues)
```

In the call to `FindNext`, no worksheet is specified so the range we want to search is on the active sheet (which may or may not be the worksheet called "Summary") in the active workbook (which may or may not be the workbook where this code is stored):

```
Set cell = Range("A1:" & ColLetter & "1").FindNext(cell)
```

To fix this, you could just specify the worksheet in the call to `FindNext`:

```
Set cell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:" & ColLetter & "1").FindNext(cell)
```

but it can make your code less error-prone if you use a variable to store the range to be searched and then just refer to that variable:

```
Dim rngToSearch As Range

Set rngToSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:" & ColLetter & "1")
Set cell = rngToSearch.Find("DESC", LookIn:=xlValues)

' do stuff with cell

Set cell = rngToSearch.FindNext(cell)
```

Comment: I'll specify the worksheet in the call FindNext, and see the results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While not a direct answer to your question per se, in this instance you would probably be better off using a generic FindAll function then processing the individual cells within the found range to get your values.

I have used some shortcuts to illustrate the process, but you should be able to adapt the FindAll call to your needs.

```
Sub ProcessDesc()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet: Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim FoundRange As Range, Cell As Range, Val As Integer

    Dim DescMaxNumber As Integer: DescMaxNumber = 0
    Dim TermDescMaxNumber As Integer: TermDescMaxNumber = 0

    Set FoundRange = FindAll("*DESC*", wsSrc.UsedRange)

    For Each Cell In FoundRange
        Val = IIf(IsNumeric(Right(Cell, 2)), CInt(Right(Cell, 2)), 0)
        If InStr(Cell, "TERMDESC") Then
            TermDescMaxNumber = IIf(Val > TermDescMaxNumber, Val, TermDescMaxNumber)
        Else
            DescMaxNumber = IIf(Val > DescMaxNumber, Val, DescMaxNumber)
        End If
    Next Cell
    Debug.Print DescMaxNumber, TermDescMaxNumber

End Sub

Private Function FindAll(What, _
    Optional SearchWhat As Variant, _
    Optional LookIn, _
    Optional LookAt, _
    Optional SearchOrder, _
    Optional SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext, _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False, _
    Optional MatchByte, _
    Optional SearchFormat) As Range

    'LookIn can be xlValues or xlFormulas, _
     LookAt can be xlWhole or xlPart, _
     SearchOrder can be xlByRows or xlByColumns, _
     SearchDirection can be xlNext, xlPrevious, _
     MatchCase, MatchByte, and SearchFormat can be True or False. _
     Before using SearchFormat = True, specify the appropriate settings for the Application.FindFormat _
     object; e.g. Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "General;-General;""-"""

    Dim SrcRange As Range
    If IsMissing(SearchWhat) Then
        Set SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Range Then
        Set SrcRange = IIf(SearchWhat.Cells.Count = 1, SearchWhat.Parent.UsedRange, SearchWhat)
    ElseIf TypeOf SearchWhat Is Worksheet Then
        Set SrcRange = SearchWhat.UsedRange
    Else: SrcRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    End If
    If SrcRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'get the first matching cell in the range first
    With SrcRange.Areas(SrcRange.Areas.Count)
        Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With

    Dim CurrRange As Range: Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=FirstCell, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
        SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)

    If Not CurrRange Is Nothing Then
        Set FindAll = CurrRange
        Do
            Set CurrRange = SrcRange.Find(What:=What, After:=CurrRange, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, _
            SearchDirection:=SearchDirection, MatchCase:=MatchCase, MatchByte:=MatchByte, SearchFormat:=SearchFormat)
            If CurrRange Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Application.Intersect(FindAll, CurrRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set FindAll = Application.Union(FindAll, CurrRange)
            Else: Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```